# How concatenate two filtered values in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, concatenation

I need to concatenate two filtered items in vue.js.

```html
<input
  :value="startDate | dateFormat + '-' + endDate | dateFormat"
/>
```

How could this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can stick with using a filter and just provide the two dates as array or object and create the string inside the filter function:

**Use as object**

```html
<input :value="{ startDate: '2020-10-10', endDate: '2021-01-01' } | dateRange"/>

...

Vue.filter("dateRange", ({ startDate, endDate }) => `${startDate} - ${endDate}`);
```

**Use as array**

```html
<input :value="['2020-10-10', '2021-01-01'] | dateRange" />

...

Vue.filter("dateRange", ([startDate, endDate]) => `${startDate} - ${endDate}`);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-monad-kdy6j?file=/src/App.vue:0-705

Answer (score 4):

This one should work

```js
data() {
  return {
    fullDate: `${this.$options.filters.dateFormat(this.startDate)} - ${this.$options.filters.dateFormat(endDate)}`,
  }
},
```

or the `computed` variant as suggested by Alberto (if your data changes, this one will be re-computed, `data` won't)

```js
computed: {
  fullDate() {
    return `${this.$options.filters.dateFormat(this.startDate)} - ${this.$options.filters.dateFormat(this.endDate)}`
  },
},
```

Then, finally

```html
<input :value="fullDate" />
```